# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL. Html.Partial()

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

There is javascript exception when I tried to use @Html.Partial() MVC method for rednering partial view. below is my function

```
function DisplayDynamicData(actionMethod) {
        var string = '';
        if (actionMethod == 'Edit') {
            string ='@Html.Partial("Edit", Model)'
            $('#divdisplay').html(string);
        }
        if (actionMethod == 'Create')
             string ='@Html.Partial("Create", Model)'
              $('#divdisplay').html(string);

    }
```

Execution Outpout

```
function DisplayDynamicData(actionMethod) {
        var string = '';
        if (actionMethod == 'Edit') {
            string ='<form action="/" id="formEdit" method="get"><input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="KxJHl9hBr1WSIQhpp7aNmw8bAVbixn8-XV3n5c--_z9azhHYqSlAMkmS-LKY7uDM0Qdj07SNrdT5JrtACZvPKO6Y7F2Quoj9Bei4RCUZfbHga51Ad0aNN9RDPEziTMTd8vkzS6I2-2Xtl8vAlMFkzyn7wXnqYkRhUvieTYPMxrM1" /><input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Id must be a number." data-val-required="The Id field is required." id="Id" name="Id" type="hidden" value="" />      <h2>Edit Product</h2>
    <div class="editor-label">
        <label for="Category">Category</label>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
   ......'
       }
   }
```

I thought, because of string is rendering in new line, this error occurs.  How to deal with this string. Please assist here

Comment: either put every thing in one liner or add a `/` at the end or concatenate the strings.

Comment: Updated answer: Based on your intentions, to "reduce page size", you really need to move to really loading the partial views dynamically (i.e. via Ajax). Have added some examples below, wher you would just inject the action urls and load the partial pages via Ajax calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use string injection to create complex elements. It is a maintenance nightmare (even without your current error).

### 1 - Inject the partial view into a template on the page (fake script block)

```
<script id="edittemplate" type="text/template">
      @Html.Partial("Edit", Model)
</script>
```

### 2 - Access it using the id

```
var edittemplate = $('#edittemplate').html();
```

### 3 - Do with it as you please

```
$('#divdisplay').html(edittemplate);
```

Repeat for as many templates as you need, each in its own script block.

*Note: I recommend a similar approach for any dynamic elements you want to create in jQuery, as inline HTML (containing text-replace markers) is far more readable and easy to modify.*

### Update (based on comment below)

The intention was to save space by not having hidden divs with each partial view. Placing the HTML into code does not reduce the page load size as the code added to the page is as large as the HTML.

What you really want (to keep page size down) is to load the partial views via Ajax when needed.

The problem then is that each partial view will need its own Model data, so you will have to pass parameters back to the server. Do that by injecting the URLs only into your jquery:

### e.g. something like

```
function DisplayDynamicData(actionMethod) {
    var url;
    switch (actionMethod)
    {
        case 'Edit':
            url ='@Url.Action("Edit")';
            break;
        case 'Create':
            url ='@Url.Action("Create")';
            break;
    }
    $.ajax({ 
          url: url, 
          success: function(data){
                $('#divdisplay').html(data);
          }
    });
}
```

or instead of the `ajax` call, the even simpler:

```
    $("#divdisplay").load(url);
```

I leave it for you to fill in the specifics you may need for parameters to the inserted `Url.Actions`

Comment: Thanks for response. This is same like putting html.paritial() into the div and show/hide that div. My intention was getting string dynamically so that page size would not increase.

Comment: Think about what you are saying... the strings are also in the page (they have to be to do Razor string injection into JS) and they take up just as much space as the HTML :) Hiding/showing divs will do the job just fine for a simple case (non-repeated data).